# Google Analytics tracking of the same website with on different domains

Tags: google-analytics

basically, my website is based on one set of html codes but it is hosted on 3 different domains. (example.com, example.sg, example.my)

So each of these websites has their unique ids for Google analytics tracking. 
Is there a way to tweak the code from Google to track all three websites respectively?

This is the current code I am using.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-38011741-2', 'versafleet.sg');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

It is from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

The flaw with the code is that it only takes in one id for example.com and there is no where to include the ids for the other 2 websites.

So is there a way to include the ids of the other 2 websites into code to track them as well? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your configuration depending on the hostname. Not tested, but it work something like this:

```
uaids = {
    "domain1.com":"UA-XXXXX-X1",
    "domain2.sg":"UA-XXXXX-X2",
    "domain3.my":"UA-XXXXX-X3",
}

ga('create', uaids[window.location.hostname], window.location.hostname);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

where the uaids-Array stores the Account Ids with the respective domain as index and the hostname is pulled via javascript from the location object to retrieve the value.

It would be more reliable to change the account id serverside (but I guess if that where an option you would not have asked).

However in your case it would be simpler to use the same account id for each domain (since apparently the pages are the same) and use view filters based in hostnames to separate the data (update: on second reading I may have misunderstood the requirements).

Unless you expect people to move between the domains and you want to track visitor sessions across domain boundaries - in that case, as already has been pointed out, you would need cross domain tracking (and you should follow Crayons link and get back to us with any problems you encounter there).

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have implemented the codes and is still waiting for response to see if it works. =) Thanks!

Comment: If this helped feel free to "accept" the answer (you should see a checkmark at the top left of the question that you can click to accept - I get some reputation points and the question does not show up in the unanswered questions list).

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics uses 1st party cookie tracking. You need to implement [cross domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain) on your pages in order for GA to track the visitor across multiple domains.